# Combobox losing properties when in form

Tags: javascript, html, combobox, autocomplete

I am using the combobox from this link: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox. When using this code on a normal page on my front-end, it works perfectly.
But when I try to integrate it into a form, it loses its properties, so it works only as  a select, but I can't type anything.
[image: As it can be seen below, it is read-only.]

The code looks somewhat like this:

```
<form>
...

<div style="float:left;margin-left:10px;">
          <label for="nextdev1" style="color:white">Next Hop</label>
          <div class="ui-widget">
            <!-- rest of code here -->
        </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: provide a jsfiddle link

Comment: Make sure you you are adding both jquery and jqueryui files at the top

Comment: @Thinker, this is how it should work. My example also extracts the options from a database, so this is why I just show you the example I found on the Internet: https://jsfiddle.net/catalina/ahjf5gxu/

Comment: I' ve added: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>`